# Json Model Class has no getter list receiver instance

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Simple JSON data fetch and show in screen the data is showing in print but while showing in screen its giving error of NoSuchMethodErrorClass 'ResponsiveObjectSettingByUser' has no instance method 'car' receiver: Instance,

**GET FUNCTION**

```
Future<ResponseObjectSettingByUser> _list;
  final String _url = '<LINK>';


Future<ResponseObjectSettingByUser> getUserSettings() async {
    ResponseObjectSettingByUser responseData = null;

    var response = await http
        .get(_url + '<link>', headers: {
      "Authorization":
          'Bearer <TOKEN>',
    });

     var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      responseJson = settingByUserModel(response.body);
      print(responseJson.toJson().toString());
    }
    return responseJson;
  }
```

**Initilize**

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

       _list = getUserSettings();
  }
```

**MODEL CLASS (ResponseObjectSettingByUser)**

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final welcome = welcomeFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

ResponseObjectSettingByUser settingByUserModel(String str) => ResponseObjectSettingByUser.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String welcomeToJson(ResponseObjectSettingByUser data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class ResponseObjectSettingByUser {
  ResponseObjectSettingByUser({
    this.array,
  });

  Array array;

  factory ResponseObjectSettingByUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ResponseObjectSettingByUser(
    array: Array.fromJson(json["array"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "array": array.toJson(),
  };
}

class Array {
  Array({
    this.car,
  });

  List<Car> car;

  factory Array.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Array(
    car: List<Car>.from(json["car"].map((x) => Car.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "car": List<dynamic>.from(car.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Car {
  Car({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.numberKmsMin,
    this.numberKmsMax,
    this.priceMin,
    this.priceMax,
    this.powerHorseMin,
    this.powerHorseMax,
    this.status,
    this.isSaved,
    this.markId,
    this.markName,
    this.markImageUrl,
    this.modelId,
    this.modelName,
    this.modelImageUrl,
    this.bodyworkId,
    this.bodyworkName,
    this.fuelId,
    this.fuelName,
    this.motorizationId,
    this.motorizationName,
    this.rimsId,
    this.rimsName,
    this.serieId,
    this.serieName,
    this.interiorEquipmentId,
    this.interiorEquipmentName,
    this.upholsteryId,
    this.upholsteryName,
    this.upholsteryLeatherFabricName,
    this.iluminationId,
    this.iluminationName,
    this.externalEquipmentId,
    this.externalEquipmentName,
    this.dateStartMin,
    this.dateEndMax,
    this.settings,
  });

  int id;
  String name;
  String numberKmsMin;
  String numberKmsMax;
  String priceMin;
  String priceMax;
  String powerHorseMin;
  String powerHorseMax;
  String status;
  int isSaved;
  int markId;
  String markName;
  String markImageUrl;
  int modelId;
  String modelName;
  String modelImageUrl;
  int bodyworkId;
  String bodyworkName;
  int fuelId;
  String fuelName;
  int motorizationId;
  String motorizationName;
  dynamic rimsId;
  dynamic rimsName;
  int serieId;
  String serieName;
  int interiorEquipmentId;
  String interiorEquipmentName;
  int upholsteryId;
  String upholsteryName;
  String upholsteryLeatherFabricName;
  int iluminationId;
  String iluminationName;
  int externalEquipmentId;
  String externalEquipmentName;
  String dateStartMin;
  String dateEndMax;
  List<Setting> settings;

  factory Car.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Car(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    numberKmsMin: json["number_kms_min"],
    numberKmsMax: json["number_kms_max"],
    priceMin: json["price_min"],
    priceMax: json["price_max"],
    powerHorseMin: json["power_horse_min"],
    powerHorseMax: json["power_horse_max"],
    status: json["status"],
    isSaved: json["is_saved"],
    markId: json["mark_id"],
    markName: json["mark_name"],
    markImageUrl: json["mark_image_url"],
    modelId: json["model_id"],
    modelName: json["model_name"],
    modelImageUrl: json["model_image_url"],
    bodyworkId: json["bodywork_id"],
    bodyworkName: json["bodywork_name"],
    fuelId: json["fuel_id"],
    fuelName: json["fuel_name"],
    motorizationId: json["Motorization_id"],
    motorizationName: json["Motorization_name"],
    rimsId: json["rims_id"],
    rimsName: json["rims_name"],
    serieId: json["serie_id"],
    serieName: json["serie_name"],
    interiorEquipmentId: json["Interior_equipment_id"],
    interiorEquipmentName: json["Interior_equipment_name"],
    upholsteryId: json["Upholstery_id"],
    upholsteryName: json["Upholstery_name"],
    upholsteryLeatherFabricName: json["Upholstery_Leather_fabric_name"],
    iluminationId: json["ilumination_id"],
    iluminationName: json["ilumination_name"],
    externalEquipmentId: json["external_equipment_id"],
    externalEquipmentName: json["external_equipment_name"],
    dateStartMin: json["date_start_min"],
    dateEndMax: json["date_end_max"],
    settings: json["settings"] == null ? null : List<Setting>.from(json["settings"].map((x) => Setting.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "number_kms_min": numberKmsMin,
    "number_kms_max": numberKmsMax,
    "price_min": priceMin,
    "price_max": priceMax,
    "power_horse_min": powerHorseMin,
    "power_horse_max": powerHorseMax,
    "status": status,
    "is_saved": isSaved,
    "mark_id": markId,
    "mark_name": markName,
    "mark_image_url": markImageUrl,
    "model_id": modelId,
    "model_name": modelName,
    "model_image_url": modelImageUrl,
    "bodywork_id": bodyworkId,
    "bodywork_name": bodyworkName,
    "fuel_id": fuelId,
    "fuel_name": fuelName,
    "Motorization_id": motorizationId,
    "Motorization_name": motorizationName,
    "rims_id": rimsId,
    "rims_name": rimsName,
    "serie_id": serieId,
    "serie_name": serieName,
    "Interior_equipment_id": interiorEquipmentId,
    "Interior_equipment_name": interiorEquipmentName,
    "Upholstery_id": upholsteryId,
    "Upholstery_name": upholsteryName,
    "Upholstery_Leather_fabric_name": upholsteryLeatherFabricName,
    "ilumination_id": iluminationId,
    "ilumination_name": iluminationName,
    "external_equipment_id": externalEquipmentId,
    "external_equipment_name": externalEquipmentName,
    "date_start_min": dateStartMin,
    "date_end_max": dateEndMax,
    "settings": settings == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(settings.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Setting {
  Setting({
    this.id,
    this.name,
  });

  int id;
  String name;

  factory Setting.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Setting(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
  };
}
```

To show data on screen using

```
   child: FutureBuilder(
                              future: getUserSettings(),
                              builder: (BuildContext context,
                                  AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                                final countries = snapshot.data;
                                if (snapshot.data == null) {
                                  //IF NULL
                                  return Container(
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Text("Loading..."),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                } else {
                                  return Stack(
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                          child: Text(snapshot.data.Car[0].id)
                                      ),
                                     ),
                                    ],
                                  );
                                }
                              },
                            ),
```

**JSON Data is like this.**

```
{
    "array": {
        "car": [
            {
                "id": 131,
                "name": "120",
                "number_kms_min": "1000",
                "number_kms_max": "10000",
                "price_min": "10000",
                "price_max": "1000",
                "power_horse_min": "100",
                "power_horse_max": "120",
                "status": "1",
                "is_saved": 0,
                "mark_id": 1,
                "mark_name": "BMW",
                "mark_image_url": "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/car-brands/550/BMW_logo-512.png",
                "model_id": 1,
                "model_name": "Serie 1",
                "model_image_url": "https://www.bmw.pt/content/dam/bmw/common/all-models/1-series/5-door/2019/navigation/bmw-1-series-modelfinder.png",
                "bodywork_id": 1,
                "bodywork_name": "Coupé",
                "fuel_id": 1,
                "fuel_name": "Gasolina",
                "Motorization_id": 1,
                "Motorization_name": "Manual",
                "rims_id": 1,
                "rims_name": "Preto fosco\r\n5 raios",
                "serie_id": 1,
                "serie_name": "120",
                "Interior_equipment_id": 1,
                "Interior_equipment_name": "Bancos desportivos\r\n",
                "Upholstery_id": 1,
                "Upholstery_name": "Preto",
                "Upholstery_Leather_fabric_name": "Preto",
                "ilumination_id": 1,
                "ilumination_name": "Iluminação ambiente",
                "external_equipment_id": 1,
                "external_equipment_name": "Para-choques desportivos",
                "date_start_min": "03/18",
                "date_end_max": "09/19"
            },
            {
                "id": 121,
                "name": "120",
                "number_kms_min": "1000",
                "number_kms_max": "10000",
                "price_min": "10000",
                "price_max": "1000",
                "power_horse_min": "100",
                "power_horse_max": "120",
                "status": "1",
                "is_saved": 0,
                "mark_id": 1,
                "mark_name": "BMW",
                "mark_image_url": "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/car-brands/550/BMW_logo-512.png",
                "model_id": 1,
                "model_name": "Serie 1",
                "model_image_url": "https://www.bmw.pt/content/dam/bmw/common/all-models/1-series/5-door/2019/navigation/bmw-1-series-modelfinder.png",
                "bodywork_id": 1,
                "bodywork_name": "Coupé",
                "fuel_id": 1,
                "fuel_name": "Gasolina",
                "Motorization_id": 1,
                "Motorization_name": "Manual",
                "rims_id": 1,
                "rims_name": "Preto fosco\r\n5 raios",
                "serie_id": 1,
                "serie_name": "120",
                "Interior_equipment_id": 1,
                "Interior_equipment_name": "Bancos desportivos\r\n",
                "Upholstery_id": 1,
                "Upholstery_name": "Preto",
                "Upholstery_Leather_fabric_name": "Preto",
                "ilumination_id": 1,
                "ilumination_name": "Iluminação ambiente",
                "external_equipment_id": 1,
                "external_equipment_name": "Para-choques desportivos",
                "date_start_min": "03/18",
                "date_end_max": "09/19"
            },
            {
                "id": 111,
                "name": "120",
                "number_kms_min": "1000",
                "number_kms_max": "10000",
                "price_min": "10000",
                "price_max": "1000",
                "power_horse_min": "100",
                "power_horse_max": "120",
                "status": "1",
                "is_saved": 0,
                "mark_id": 1,
                "mark_name": "BMW",
                "mark_image_url": "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/car-brands/550/BMW_logo-512.png",
                "model_id": 1,
                "model_name": "Serie 1",
                "model_image_url": "https://www.bmw.pt/content/dam/bmw/common/all-models/1-series/5-door/2019/navigation/bmw-1-series-modelfinder.png",
                "bodywork_id": 1,
                "bodywork_name": "Coupé",
                "fuel_id": 1,
                "fuel_name": "Gasolina",
                "Motorization_id": 1,
                "Motorization_name": "Manual",
                "rims_id": 1,
                "rims_name": "Preto fosco\r\n5 raios",
                "serie_id": 1,
                "serie_name": "120",
                "Interior_equipment_id": 1,
                "Interior_equipment_name": "Bancos desportivos\r\n",
                "Upholstery_id": 1,
                "Upholstery_name": "Preto",
                "Upholstery_Leather_fabric_name": "Preto",
                "ilumination_id": 1,
                "ilumination_name": "Iluminação ambiente",
                "external_equipment_id": 1,
                "external_equipment_name": "Para-choques desportivos",
                "date_start_min": "03/18",
                "date_end_max": "09/19"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you trying to display the data ?

Comment: Please share more code. There are methods used here that aren't defined.

Comment: Really thankful for reply, I edited the code with json data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `AsyncSnapshot<ResponseObjectSettingByUser>` and check `connectionState` and use `snapshot.data.array.car.length` in `ListView`

code snippet

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: _list,
    builder:
        (context, AsyncSnapshot<ResponseObjectSettingByUser> snapshot) {
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.none:
          return Text('none');
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        case ConnectionState.active:
          return Text('');
        case ConnectionState.done:
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(
              '${snapshot.error}',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
            );
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.array.car.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

ResponseObjectSettingByUser settingByUserModel(String str) =>
    ResponseObjectSettingByUser.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String welcomeToJson(ResponseObjectSettingByUser data) =>
    json.encode(data.toJson());

class ResponseObjectSettingByUser {
  ResponseObjectSettingByUser({
    this.array,
  });

  Array array;

  factory ResponseObjectSettingByUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      ResponseObjectSettingByUser(
        array: Array.fromJson(json["array"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "array": array.toJson(),
      };
}

class Array {
  Array({
    this.car,
  });

  List<Car> car;

  factory Array.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Array(
        car: List<Car>.from(json["car"].map((x) => Car.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "car": List<dynamic>.from(car.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Car {
  Car({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.numberKmsMin,
    this.numberKmsMax,
    this.priceMin,
    this.priceMax,
    this.powerHorseMin,
    this.powerHorseMax,
    this.status,
    this.isSaved,
    this.markId,
    this.markName,
    this.markImageUrl,
    this.modelId,
    this.modelName,
    this.modelImageUrl,
    this.bodyworkId,
    this.bodyworkName,
    this.fuelId,
    this.fuelName,
    this.motorizationId,
    this.motorizationName,
    this.rimsId,
    this.rimsName,
    this.serieId,
    this.serieName,
    this.interiorEquipmentId,
    this.interiorEquipmentName,
    this.upholsteryId,
    this.upholsteryName,
    this.upholsteryLeatherFabricName,
    this.iluminationId,
    this.iluminationName,
    this.externalEquipmentId,
    this.externalEquipmentName,
    this.dateStartMin,
    this.dateEndMax,
    this.settings,
  });

  int id;
  String name;
  String numberKmsMin;
  String numberKmsMax;
  String priceMin;
  String priceMax;
  String powerHorseMin;
  String powerHorseMax;
  String status;
  int isSaved;
  int markId;
  String markName;
  String markImageUrl;
  int modelId;
  String modelName;
  String modelImageUrl;
  int bodyworkId;
  String bodyworkName;
  int fuelId;
  String fuelName;
  int motorizationId;
  String motorizationName;
  dynamic rimsId;
  dynamic rimsName;
  int serieId;
  String serieName;
  int interiorEquipmentId;
  String interiorEquipmentName;
  int upholsteryId;
  String upholsteryName;
  String upholsteryLeatherFabricName;
  int iluminationId;
  String iluminationName;
  int externalEquipmentId;
  String externalEquipmentName;
  String dateStartMin;
  String dateEndMax;
  List<Setting> settings;

  factory Car.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Car(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        numberKmsMin: json["number_kms_min"],
        numberKmsMax: json["number_kms_max"],
        priceMin: json["price_min"],
        priceMax: json["price_max"],
        powerHorseMin: json["power_horse_min"],
        powerHorseMax: json["power_horse_max"],
        status: json["status"],
        isSaved: json["is_saved"],
        markId: json["mark_id"],
        markName: json["mark_name"],
        markImageUrl: json["mark_image_url"],
        modelId: json["model_id"],
        modelName: json["model_name"],
        modelImageUrl: json["model_image_url"],
        bodyworkId: json["bodywork_id"],
        bodyworkName: json["bodywork_name"],
        fuelId: json["fuel_id"],
        fuelName: json["fuel_name"],
        motorizationId: json["Motorization_id"],
        motorizationName: json["Motorization_name"],
        rimsId: json["rims_id"],
        rimsName: json["rims_name"],
        serieId: json["serie_id"],
        serieName: json["serie_name"],
        interiorEquipmentId: json["Interior_equipment_id"],
        interiorEquipmentName: json["Interior_equipment_name"],
        upholsteryId: json["Upholstery_id"],
        upholsteryName: json["Upholstery_name"],
        upholsteryLeatherFabricName: json["Upholstery_Leather_fabric_name"],
        iluminationId: json["ilumination_id"],
        iluminationName: json["ilumination_name"],
        externalEquipmentId: json["external_equipment_id"],
        externalEquipmentName: json["external_equipment_name"],
        dateStartMin: json["date_start_min"],
        dateEndMax: json["date_end_max"],
        settings: json["settings"] == null
            ? null
            : List<Setting>.from(
                json["settings"].map((x) => Setting.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "number_kms_min": numberKmsMin,
        "number_kms_max": numberKmsMax,
        "price_min": priceMin,
        "price_max": priceMax,
        "power_horse_min": powerHorseMin,
        "power_horse_max": powerHorseMax,
        "status": status,
        "is_saved": isSaved,
        "mark_id": markId,
        "mark_name": markName,
        "mark_image_url": markImageUrl,
        "model_id": modelId,
        "model_name": modelName,
        "model_image_url": modelImageUrl,
        "bodywork_id": bodyworkId,
        "bodywork_name": bodyworkName,
        "fuel_id": fuelId,
        "fuel_name": fuelName,
        "Motorization_id": motorizationId,
        "Motorization_name": motorizationName,
        "rims_id": rimsId,
        "rims_name": rimsName,
        "serie_id": serieId,
        "serie_name": serieName,
        "Interior_equipment_id": interiorEquipmentId,
        "Interior_equipment_name": interiorEquipmentName,
        "Upholstery_id": upholsteryId,
        "Upholstery_name": upholsteryName,
        "Upholstery_Leather_fabric_name": upholsteryLeatherFabricName,
        "ilumination_id": iluminationId,
        "ilumination_name": iluminationName,
        "external_equipment_id": externalEquipmentId,
        "external_equipment_name": externalEquipmentName,
        "date_start_min": dateStartMin,
        "date_end_max": dateEndMax,
        "settings": settings == null
            ? null
            : List<dynamic>.from(settings.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Setting {
  Setting({
    this.id,
    this.name,
  });

  int id;
  String name;

  factory Setting.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Setting(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
      };
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<ResponseObjectSettingByUser> _list;

  Future<ResponseObjectSettingByUser> getUserSettings() async {
    ResponseObjectSettingByUser responseData = null;

    /*var response = await http
        .get(_url + '<link>', headers: {
      "Authorization":
      'Bearer <TOKEN>',
    });*/

    String jsonString = '''
    {
    "array": {
        "car": [
            {
                "id": 131,
                "name": "120",
                "number_kms_min": "1000",
                "number_kms_max": "10000",
                "price_min": "10000",
                "price_max": "1000",
                "power_horse_min": "100",
                "power_horse_max": "120",
                "status": "1",
                "is_saved": 0,
                "mark_id": 1,
                "mark_name": "BMW",
                "mark_image_url": "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/car-brands/550/BMW_logo-512.png",
                "model_id": 1,
                "model_name": "Serie 1",
                "model_image_url": "https://www.bmw.pt/content/dam/bmw/common/all-models/1-series/5-door/2019/navigation/bmw-1-series-modelfinder.png",
                "bodywork_id": 1,
                "bodywork_name": "Coupé",
                "fuel_id": 1,
                "fuel_name": "Gasolina",
                "Motorization_id": 1,
                "Motorization_name": "Manual",
                "rims_id": 1,
                "rims_name": "Preto fosco\r\n5 raios",
                "serie_id": 1,
                "serie_name": "120",
                "Interior_equipment_id": 1,
                "Interior_equipment_name": "Bancos desportivos\r\n",
                "Upholstery_id": 1,
                "Upholstery_name": "Preto",
                "Upholstery_Leather_fabric_name": "Preto",
                "ilumination_id": 1,
                "ilumination_name": "Iluminação ambiente",
                "external_equipment_id": 1,
                "external_equipment_name": "Para-choques desportivos",
                "date_start_min": "03/18",
                "date_end_max": "09/19"
            },
            {
                "id": 121,
                "name": "120",
                "number_kms_min": "1000",
                "number_kms_max": "10000",
                "price_min": "10000",
                "price_max": "1000",
                "power_horse_min": "100",
                "power_horse_max": "120",
                "status": "1",
                "is_saved": 0,
                "mark_id": 1,
                "mark_name": "BMW",
                "mark_image_url": "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/car-brands/550/BMW_logo-512.png",
                "model_id": 1,
                "model_name": "Serie 1",
                "model_image_url": "https://www.bmw.pt/content/dam/bmw/common/all-models/1-series/5-door/2019/navigation/bmw-1-series-modelfinder.png",
                "bodywork_id": 1,
                "bodywork_name": "Coupé",
                "fuel_id": 1,
                "fuel_name": "Gasolina",
                "Motorization_id": 1,
                "Motorization_name": "Manual",
                "rims_id": 1,
                "rims_name": "Preto fosco\r\n5 raios",
                "serie_id": 1,
                "serie_name": "120",
                "Interior_equipment_id": 1,
                "Interior_equipment_name": "Bancos desportivos\r\n",
                "Upholstery_id": 1,
                "Upholstery_name": "Preto",
                "Upholstery_Leather_fabric_name": "Preto",
                "ilumination_id": 1,
                "ilumination_name": "Iluminação ambiente",
                "external_equipment_id": 1,
                "external_equipment_name": "Para-choques desportivos",
                "date_start_min": "03/18",
                "date_end_max": "09/19"
            },
            {
                "id": 111,
                "name": "120",
                "number_kms_min": "1000",
                "number_kms_max": "10000",
                "price_min": "10000",
                "price_max": "1000",
                "power_horse_min": "100",
                "power_horse_max": "120",
                "status": "1",
                "is_saved": 0,
                "mark_id": 1,
                "mark_name": "BMW",
                "mark_image_url": "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/car-brands/550/BMW_logo-512.png",
                "model_id": 1,
                "model_name": "Serie 1",
                "model_image_url": "https://www.bmw.pt/content/dam/bmw/common/all-models/1-series/5-door/2019/navigation/bmw-1-series-modelfinder.png",
                "bodywork_id": 1,
                "bodywork_name": "Coupé",
                "fuel_id": 1,
                "fuel_name": "Gasolina",
                "Motorization_id": 1,
                "Motorization_name": "Manual",
                "rims_id": 1,
                "rims_name": "Preto fosco\r\n5 raios",
                "serie_id": 1,
                "serie_name": "120",
                "Interior_equipment_id": 1,
                "Interior_equipment_name": "Bancos desportivos\r\n",
                "Upholstery_id": 1,
                "Upholstery_name": "Preto",
                "Upholstery_Leather_fabric_name": "Preto",
                "ilumination_id": 1,
                "ilumination_name": "Iluminação ambiente",
                "external_equipment_id": 1,
                "external_equipment_name": "Para-choques desportivos",
                "date_start_min": "03/18",
                "date_end_max": "09/19"
            }
        ]
    }
}
    ''';

    http.Response response = http.Response(jsonString, 200);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String postProcessing =
          response.body.replaceAll('\n', "").replaceAll('\r', "");
      var responseJson = settingByUserModel(postProcessing);
      print(responseJson.toJson().toString());
      return responseJson;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _list = getUserSettings();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _list,
            builder:
                (context, AsyncSnapshot<ResponseObjectSettingByUser> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('none');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(
                      '${snapshot.error}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.array.car.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Card(
                              elevation: 6.0,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 6.0,
                                    bottom: 6.0,
                                    left: 8.0,
                                    right: 8.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(snapshot
                                        .data.array.car[index].markName),
                                    Spacer(),
                                    Text(snapshot
                                        .data.array.car[index].id.toString()),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ));
                        });
                  }
              }
            }));
  }
}
```